# How to load a webpage as nice and as smooth as it can get

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css

I want to imitate in my project one of [apple's pages](http://www.apple.com/mac/) behaviors (best viewed on FF, Chrome, Safari):

1. at the first moment the page is empty except the header - **but the height of the page is already set to the final height when all will be loaded** so the browser scrollbar doesn't change.
2. the elements of the page (main banner, medium-level banners, last-banners, footer etc) appear one by one from top to bottom in a smooth fade-in.

These 2 things makes the page loading looks absolutely smooth and stunning.

In General this is how my page will look like:

```
<header></header>
<div id="content>
     <div id="mainImage"></div>
     <div id="gallery"></div>
     <div id="info"></div> 
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

**I have some guesses how apple did it but I am not sure:**

1. All the page is fully loaded though everything is in `opacity:0` and only after that there is a script that animates each elements appearance one by one. I assume that is not efficient.
2. All the page is built on an ajax call for each section: when it finishes to load then it will appear. that also doesn't fit because they always appear from top to bottom and not by what comes first. and how do they calculate the page's height at the begining.

I'd be happy for ideas, and for a way to make it as much efficient and general that the code will be easy to use.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apple site uses [scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/). Their webpage has a free download of the library, as well as documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery and fade in each element in the order you want and in its callback you fade in the next one.

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/Pd7We/

```
$('#nav').fadeIn(500,function() {
    $('#main').fadeIn(1000,function() {
       $('#footer').fadeIn(1000);     
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.loading').show();
    $('.main').hide();
});
$(document).on('load', function () {
    $('.main').fadeIn(500);
    $('.loading').hide();
});
```